# Entering date manually inside a jQuery datepicker does not update the widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

It happens once in a while but if i enter the date direclty in the input, the **widget does not update with the date i manually entered**.

See by yourself : http://screencast.com/t/Fz2ecsGte3T (the date format is dd/mm/yyyy).

I don't know why or how this happens. But it happens (10% of the time).

My Jquery versions are :

- jquery-1.4.3.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.js

Unfortunatly, I cant update jquery to latest version. (But i can update to another minor version if this bug is jquery 1.4.3 related).

Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868843/jquery-datepicker-date-manual-input hope this will help you

Comment: I added the constrainInput: false, but i've updated my question. see edit. ;-)

Comment: date picker does not allow except numbers  and '/' `$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ constrainInput: false });` will allow you all options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a little extra whitespace preventing the widget to update. Removing it fixed the problem.
(also, constrainInput is good to know)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

```
str: '         spaceces left & right         ';
$.trim(str);
```