# How to make datepicker textbox editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datepicker

I am using datepicker in my application for letting the user entering dates. But what I want is that the user should be able to enter the dates manually as well into the textbox using keyboard and then the date-picker automatically should be able to identify the date and accept it.

Here is the JS used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getMetricName()
    {
      var today = new Date();
       var maxdate=  new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),(today.getDate()-    1),"23","59","59");
              $(function() {
                   $('#start_date').datetimepicker({timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
                      dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
                      maxDate: maxdate});

              $('#end_date').datetimepicker({timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
                      dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
                      maxDate: maxdate});

      });
</script>
```

And below is the simple datepicker commands in html.

```
<td><input class="datepicker" name="start_date" value=""  /></td>
 <td><input id="end_date" name="end_date" value=""  /></td>
```

Please help.

Comment: If user entered `01-10-2014` then can you tell me is it *1st October 2014* or *10th January 2014*? How can you stop user entering wrong date? How are you going to decide date pattern?

Comment: `$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ constrainInput: false });` Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868843/jquery-datepicker-date-manual-input

Comment: @Aniket I guess a `placeholder` can do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Datepicker Widget from JQuery, you can use the next option;

```
constrainInput: false
```

like

```
$('#start_date').datetimepicker({timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
                  dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
                  constrainInput: false, 
                  maxDate: maxdate});
```

[API information constrainInput](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-constrainInput) + 
[API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for further documentation if you need any.