# Setting dateFormat of jquery ui datepicker restricts free text in input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using a jquery ui datepicker.
I simply want to set the dateFormat to something like: "dd/mm/yy", so my javascript is:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

And the relevant html is:

```
<input type='text' id='datepicker'>
```

However, doing this restricts the text that can be entered into the input element (I can't enter "-" or "." for example).

http://jsfiddle.net/5sVpA/3/

I need this functionality because I want users to be able to also freely enter their date with some other "date delimiting" options (eg: "5-5-16"). This is not possible because the "-" symbol cannot be entered after specifying the "dateFormat" option.

Is there a way to fix this or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer.
There is a "constrainInput" option that must be set to false.
So:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
     constrainInput: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,you need to specify formats in parseDate method

```
  $.datepicker.inputFormats = ["dd-mm-yy", "dd/mm/yy", "dd mm yy"];//list formats to be accepted here

$.datepicker.originalParseDate = $.datepicker.parseDate;

$.datepicker.parseDate = function (format, value, settings) {
var date;

function testParse(format, value, settings) {
    if ( ! date ) {
        try {
            date = $.datepicker.originalParseDate(format, value, settings);
        } catch (Error) {
        }
    }
}

testParse(format, value, settings);
for(var n = 0, stop = $.datepicker.inputFormats ? $.datepicker.inputFormats.length : 0; n < stop; n++){
    testParse($.datepicker.inputFormats[n], value, settings);
};
return date;
};
```

The above code is from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839641/4810628

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for your post.

try this code.

```
$('#txtDatePicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-y'
});
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I would like the freedom to type a variety of symbols in the text field (eg: be able to type all formats: "5-5-16", "5/5/16", "5.5.15" by hand) as well as have the datepicker output the format "dd/mm/yy"

Comment: ohhh my god, try this below code, its may be help to you, $('#txtDatePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', constrainInput: false // its allow manual date entry });

please find below url for more.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868843/jquery-datepicker-date-manual-input